# I am not importing drivers for dell E7450 in sccm 2012

Tags: sccm

I am not import drivers for dell E7450 in sccm 2012. I have downloaded the .cb file from dell website.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is a Q&A website for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

What version of SCCM are you using?  If you're on SCCM2012 R2 SP1 or 2012 SP2, be warned that there is an issue when you import drivers that will make the driver package **very, very big**.  If this happens to you, install CU1.

Importing drivers is easy.  You've got the .cab file, just do this:

- Unzip the .cab file to a file share somewhere on your SCCM server.  I'd call it \SCCM\driverSource.
- Launch SCCM and go to Software Library \ Operating System Deployment \ Drivers
- Right click the drivers and choose import, then specify the path you exported the drivers too
- When you're prompted during the wizard, dump all of the drivers into a new driver package, one for each separate computer model.  Don't put all of your drivers for more than one model in a package.
- Push this out to your distribution points. If you don't have some, make some and add them to a DP group associated with the physical locations where you want to image by making boundaries for each place.

That's the 10,000 foot tour of how to do it.